# How to write a Query that should return me foreign key only if it satisfy all the conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Parent table A as

```
**SID name**
1     ABC
2     XYZ
3     ZYK
.........
```

and child table B as

```
SID Status
1   New
1   Open
1   Closed
2   Open
2   Open
3   New
3   Open
3   Closed
3   REJ
```

Now my question is i want to fire query against the child table, and want to find out only the SID where all the status are same and status should be open only.

**Note:** In the above example i have should only few status against SID, but there are multiple status. and eveytime i want this query against different status.

**Expected result:**
For time Being if i will consider the status as open, then SID 2 is only there which has all records with open status.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause.  The following works assuming that `status` is never `NULL`:

```
select sid
from b
group by sid
having min(status) = max(status) and
       min(status) = 'open';
```

If you have `NULL` values, you can use this `having` clause:

```
having count(*) = count(status) and
       min(status) = max(status) and
       min(status) = 'open';
```

Comment: what I will get by min(status). that is char field.

Comment: @BharatGurbani . . . You will get the smallest value, using the ordering specified by the collation for the column/database/server.  This would typically be the first one in alphabetical ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like  Gordon said you need to use aggregation, you can use count too:

```
SELECT sid
from b
Group by sid
having count(Distinct status)=1 and min(status)='open'
```

The min(status) will get you the first alphabetic solution.

Comment: please explain what min(status) will fetch me

Comment: The min(status) will get you the first alphabetic solution.